# How to combine click and mouseenter in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive to have a sorting icon on a table column (fa-caret-up, fa-caret-down) When i mouseenter on the column header, it should show opposite direction of existing otherwise default direction desc.
I am able to get the events click, mouseenter and mouseleave.
Now the problem is, when you go over a column to click, triggering is not appropriate and it is removing sort icon.
 Is there a way to combine both click and mouseenter events to trigger first click and mouseenter event next?
This is my code.I need to implement something like ele.bind("click mouseenter") or order events click then implement mouseeneter:

```
var upSortClass = "fa fa-caret-up";
var downSortClass = "fa fa-caret-down";
var iconClass = ".icon-sort";
var addIconClass ="";
var removeIconClass ="";

ele.bind('click', function () {
    var ic = ele.find(iconClass);
    ic.addClass(addIconClass);
    addIconClass ="";
});
ele.bind('mouseenter', function () {
    var ic = ele.find(iconClass);
    var sortUp = ic.hasClass(upSortClass);
    var sortDown = ic.hasClass(downSortClass);

    if(sortUp) {
        addIconClass = upSortClass;
        removeIconClass = downSortClass;
        ic.removeClass(upSortClass);
        ic.addClass(downSortClass);
    }
    if(sortDown) {
        addIconClass = downSortClass;
        removeIconClass = upSortClass;
        ic.removeClass(downSortClass);
        ic.addClass(upSortClass);
    }
    if(!sortUp && !sortDown) {
        removeIconClass = downSortClass;
        ic.addClass(downSortClass);
    }
});
ele.bind('mouseleave', function () {
    var ic = ele.find(iconClass);
    ic.removeClass(removeIconClass);
    ic.addClass(addIconClass);
    addIconClass ="";
    removeIconClass ="";
});
```

please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot trigger mouseenter.

Comment: I am busy and have some little knowledge about this, I will help you on Monday

Comment: @BhojendraNepal can I trigger hover and also implement mouseleave.